# Parsley validation custom pattern not working

Tags: php, regex, parsley.js

I'm writing custom validation

This works:

```
data-parsley-pattern="#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}" //Hex color #32a852
```

But this not working

```
data-parsley-pattern="^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{8}$" //AB12345678
```

I also not working

```
data-parsley-pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{8}" //AB12345678
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

style='text-transform:uppercase' was causing the Error. 
 it seems data was still in lowercase and mismatching with pattern.